# APA - More sources from same author and same year than there are characters in the alphabet?

Tags: apa

In my research, I've used 37 articles from https://developer.mozilla.org/ as sources. These are articles written by multiple contributors, kind of like how Wikipedia works. From what I understand, you need to add lower-case letters to your sources if they are from the same author and the same year, but the alphabet doesn't have enough characters to do that in my case. Can anyone offer me some advice on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common trick is to go beyond '*z*' by using two-letter indices.

Thus, the first 26 references are *a-z*.
The next 26 are *aa-az*.
Then *ba-bz* etc.

For an example of this, just look at the subversions of the [IEEE802.11](http://www.ieee802.org/11/) WiFi standard.  Your router will have been commonly sold as complying with IEEE802.11b then IEEE802.11g / n etc.  Then to IEEE802.11ac.  These will be well known to most computer users.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much!